# Applescript - What does "AXMain" mean?

Tags: applescript

In this script:

```
    global frontApp, frontAppName, windowTitle

    set windowTitle to ""
    tell application "System Events"
        set frontApp to first application process whose frontmost is true
        set frontAppName to name of frontApp
        tell process frontAppName
            tell (1st window whose value of attribute "AXMain" is true)
                set windowTitle to value of attribute "AXTitle"
            end tell
        end tell
    end tell

    return {frontAppName, windowTitle}
```

What does "AXMain" mean? I cannot find the documentation or other questions asking about this anywhere!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`AX` is a class prefix which represents *Accessible*.

`AXMain` of a window means *Is this window the main window of the application*.

Comment: Thanks! Do you remember where you found this out? I.e. if there is hidden documentation somewhere?

Comment: There is an [Accessibility Programming Guide for OS X](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Accessibility/Conceptual/AccessibilityMacOSX/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001078-CH254-SW1) which explains the technology. The properties are not described in detail but most of them are self-explanatory.